# Can I install all my old and new different graphics cards and use them for OpenCL GPGPU computing?

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, opencl

I love developing applications with openCL and run them on my graphics card, but I don't really know how it connects with my hardware. I right now only use my GTX 970 for that, but I still have a GTX 760 and an HD5770 lying around doing nothing. Assuming I have the necessary hardware requirements to connect them all, would they be able contribute their processing power? I know how to address multiple devices with openCL, but how would I set up the drivers to accommodate three different graphics cards from two manufacturers?

I am dual booting Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes; OpenCL programs support doing this.

Comment: But does Windows? Or rather the Nvidia driver? I read that when the Nvidia driver is installed, no AMD cards are allowed to operate by it.

Comment: You shouldn't have a problem with installing both `AMD` and `Nvidia` device drivers.